# Defining self-referential structs in a C header file (.h)?

Tags: c, header

I'm trying to create a struct used in two .c source files to make a simple linked list structure. I thought it would save time to create a struct in the header file, however, I get a 'parse error before *' error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
/*
 * Structures.h
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 17, 2011
 *      Author: timgreene
 */

#ifndef STRUCTURES_H_
#define STRUCTURES_H_

typedef struct list_struct {
    int data;
    struct list_struct* next;
    struct list_struct* prev;
} list;

#endif /* STRUCTURES_H_ */
```

Edit: I did originally omit a detail that is, I'm actually compiling with xcc from the XMOS toolchain. I still don't understand that there would be a difference in `.h` file syntax.

Could it be a compilation flag I'm using?

Here's the console printout:

```
xcc -O0 -g -Wall -c -MMD -MP -MF"filter.d" -MT"filter.d filter.o " -target=XC-1A -o filter.o "../filter.xc"
In file included from ../filter.xc:15:
Structures.h:13: error: parse error before '*' token
Structures.h:14: error: parse error before '*' token
Structures.h:15: error: parse error before '}' token
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me. (GCC 4.5).

Comment: Note that identifiers beginning with underscores "_" are reserved, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Your code is correct; the error lies elsewhere.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't think so for C, as long as the second isn't capital. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Isn't it double underscore or underscore+capital letter?

Comment: @Pubby,Owen: See C99 7.1.3, 2nd bullet point.

Comment: Do you get the same error without using typedef?

Comment: Show the exact error, please.

Comment: Do you include this header in all `.c` files where you use `struct _list` ?

Comment: Is anyone familiar with XMOS at all? Sorry that I didn't mention this in the original post, changes are up above.

Comment: @TimGreene - We don't need to be to know that, if it is even remotely C-related, the code you've shown us should compile fine. Verify that this is the code you're working with, and post the exact error messages (with line numbers - is it an error on both lines or just one?), and if necessary the exact source of the header files.

Comment: @ChrisLutz - Just updated the question, does it make it any clearer?

Comment: @TimGreene: You will need to create a self-contained test-case (see http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking around in some of the XMOS documentation, it seems the problem is that **XC is not C**, it's just a C-like language.  From the "XC Programming Guide":

> XC provides many of the same capabilities as C, the main omission being support
>   for pointers.

...which explains why it doesn't accept the `next` and `prev` pointers in your structure.

Apparently xcc lets you mix C and XC sources, though, so if you were to limit your use of the structure to C code it should work.  From the "XCC Command-Line Manual", it appears that anything with a `.xc` extension (as in the command line you used above) is treated as XC, rather than C, source code by default.  This can be overridden by placing the option `-xc` before the C sources on the command line and `-x` afterward (or just rename the files with a `.c` extension).

If you *must* use XC rather than C, you may need to find another way of doing things (arrays, maybe?).

Comment: Oh wow! This is an embarrassing omission on my part, thanks kindly Dmitri! I feel quite humiliated by the last hour or so...

Comment: Also, for anyone else struggling with the same issue, it's simple to include normal C code in XC using a header file, so outsource your data structure requirements out of the .xc file if possible, certainly don't define any pointers in any header file used by an .xc module, or you'll look like a fool.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a forward declaration of `struct list_struct`:

```
struct list_struct;
typedef struct list_struct {
    int data;
    struct list_struct* next;
    struct list_struct* prev;
} list;
```

Perhaps your compiler doesn't recognize the identifier in the middle of its own definition, I'm not sure what the standards say about that (if anything).

For those that don't already know, this is also the way to deal with circular dependencies in `struct` definitions:

```
struct a;
struct b;

struct a {
    int x;
    struct b *y;
};

struct b {
    int x;
    struct a *y;
};
```

Comment: The OP's code is perfectly standards-compliant.  If the compiler doesn't support it, then the compiler needs to be thrown away.

Comment: -1 your example of circular dependencies would, if it were legal C code, create infinitely large types. What would `sizeof(struct a)` return?